# What is the difference between “tedious” and “bored”? Are they identical or are there nuances?

Tags: difference

As I compile my vocabulary list, I pass by a lot of words that seem identical. For example, **“tedious”** and **“bored”**. I've researched the two words:

> **[bored:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bored)** feeling weary because one is unoccupied or lacks interest in one's current activity
>
> **[tedious:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tedious)** too long, slow, or dull: tiresome or monotonous.

Does that imply that **tedious** is doing something that I like (but the process is slow so I say it's a tedious task), but **bored** is when I do something that I don't like or have no interest in, for example doing homework for school?

Are these words identical or do they have subtle nuances? If there are differences, then when should I use each word?

Comment: @Tyler James Young because i wasn't able to find a proper title for the question, i wanted to ask about other meaning like versus & against as in my country there's a debate around these two words can i ask them in the same topic ?or should i ask each question in a new topic ?

Comment: Ask about the difference between those words in a separate question.

Comment: As for this one, the main difference between these exact words as written is that they apply to different _classes_ of thing; “bored” describes the status of a person, while “tedious” describes a task. **Tedious** _events_ tend to leave _people_ **bored,** but you'd never use one of these words in place of the other.

Comment: @Tyler James Young i'm very grateful to you, thanks a lot

Comment: `Tedious` = `boring`. So, the difference is simple as `bored` vs. `boring`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These two words refer to the same feeling, but from different perspectives.

***How I feel*** is bored. ***What I am doing*** is tedious.

I am bored because my job is tedious. It bores me.

Answer (score 5):

The two concepts are very much related, and both are used to describe monotonous situations. However, while *tedious* implies *repetitive* or *monotonous* – it isn't necessarily negative.

A woodcarver, for example, might painstakingly carve a beautiful piece with hundreds if not thousands of careful and meticulous cuts. Rather than finding this tedious work *boring*, though, she might describe it as *relaxing* or even *comforting*. In other words, one antonym for *tedious* would be *exciting*, but another antonym might be *stressful*. A toll-taker might have a tedious job, but, conceivably, the toll-taker might thankful for that tedium, particularly if it's someone who prefers a job that is steeped in routine.

On the other hand, *boring* seems to connote being **too** unspectacular, to the point where someone would prefer more excitement or activity.

While both words can be (and often are) used in a negative sense, I think *tedious* can be more neutral in some contexts. I think you correctly touched on this in your question when you talked about doing something that you enjoy even if the process is slow.

Comment: that was brilliant, I've learned a lot from your comment it was insightful thank you

Answer (score 2):

The **activity** or the **material** is tedious. The **person** is bored.

Put another way, something that is tedious is bor**ing.** The tedious (boring) material makes you bored.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues.

One: As others have noted, "bored" describes the state of mind of the person, while "tedious" describes a characteristic of the thing.

A person can be tedious, but that means that he is tedious to others. An activity cannot be bored. You cannot say, "My math homework is bored." You can say, "My math homework is boring." Meaning, it causes boredom.

Two: "Tedious" means repetitive, monotonous, or long and drawn out. Those are certainly attributes of a task that can cause boredom. But they are not the only possible things that can cause boredom. I might be bored by a task that is highly varied just because it doesn't interest me. Like, I think writing poetry is boring because I'm just not interested. But writing poetry is a highly creative endeavor. I don't think it would be correct to call it tedious.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the different perspectives stated above the way I see it:

bored is a *passive* sense verb and tedious is the *active* sense verb.

In other words, if you are doing *nothing* or *nothing* is happening to you can use **bored** but if you are *doing* something or something *is happening* to you can use **tedious**.

Here some extra information that I found on **boredom** which re-enforces the passivity of the term:

**Bored** - when an individual is left without anything in particular to do, and *not interested* in their surroundings.

I would say **boredom** is a state in which you fall into through a tedious action or a disinterested state.

Applying to others the word "**boring**"(adv.) can be applied to an item or person which is seen as uninteresting to you. The *actions* of that item may be said to be **tedious**.

(Don't get *too* **bored**!)