# What is the difference among "tiresome", "boring” and "tedious"?

Tags: difference

I looked up these word in http://en.oxforddictionaries.com:

For `"boring"`, the definition is `"Not interesting; tedious"`. That makes me think that `"boring"` and `"tedious"` are nearly the same.

For `"tedious"`, the definition is `"Too long, slow, or dull; tiresome or monotonous"`. Again this seems to me that `"tedious"` and `"tiresome"` are interchanable while talking about a "task".

For `"tiresome"`, the definition is `"Causing one to feel bored or annoyed"`. I think a `"boring"` thing also `"causes one to feel bored"`.

So the only difference I could think of is that `"tedious"` has to be used with "time", but the other two does not have to.

Is there any other difference amoung them? e.g.:

> 1. It is a `boring` meeting.
> 2. It is a `tiresome` meeting.
> 3. It is a `tedious` meeting.

Comment: Have you looked these words up in a good dictionary, like this one? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tiresome

Comment: Yes, I did. For "tiresome", it says "Causing one to feel bored or annoyed", I think a boring thing also makes people feel bored, therefore I can not figure out the difference between them. For "tedious", it says "Too long, slow, or dull; tiresome or monotonous", which contains a "tiresome", so I think they are very similar too.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the definitions you found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between “tedious” and “bored”? Are they identical or are there nuances?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13672/what-is-the-difference-between-tedious-and-bored-are-they-identical-or-are)

Comment: @verbose: the answer to your possible duplicate focuses on the fact that one word refers to how somebody feels, and the other refers to something that makes somebody feel like that. It does not address the differences in meaning between the words in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise what the dictionary entries say:

If something does not hold your interest, it can be described as boring, regardless of how long you spend doing it.

If something does not hold your interest, it can be described as tiresome, regardless of how long you spend doing it.

If something does not hold your interest and you have to spend a long time doing it, it can be described as tedious.

If something is annoying, it can be described as tiresome whether or not it is boring or tedious, and regardless of how long you spend doing it.